# jq - bash script for csv to json with arrays?

Tags: json, csv, jq

I've been using jq to parse JSON from curl responses and it's been super cool for that.

What I'm trying to do now is take various bits of information I've cobbled together in a CSV and get it into JSON so that I can curl it to an API. Here's my example JSON that I'm trying to replicate programmatically:

```
{
  "title": "New Story",
  "channels": [
    {
      "id": "65tyc2TLUZsO"
    }
  ],
  "description": "Story Description Here",
  "new_files": [
    {
      "filename": "419155345a7b449df3baca76694b64efbec9bcf3983b51e02f92e7ef29fc26ee.pptx",
      "description": "File Description ABC"
    },
    {
    "filename": "5cdd90989c03d3fb619df6f9294b1fcb537b4f3b55737465930b220507f30e75.pdf",
    "description":"File Description XYZ"
    }
  ]
}
```

The title, id, description, filename, and (file) description values are all in a CSV. What I can't figure out is how to generate JSON from what I've got.

I don't know how I should be formatting my CSV file given that:
1. I have some key:value pairs at the top level (title, description) and then some arrays with key:value pairs as well. I can tell you I will always have 1 value in the "channels" array.
2. I won't have the same number of files in the new_files array so being able to dynamically build that array would be great.

If anyone's got a tutorial to point me to on this kind of thing, that'd be awesome. I'm sure I'm not the first to try this. I'm using bash scripts for this stuff (as it's what I know) but I'm not opposed to other solutions. (It'd just take longer for me to learn.)

At a high level I understand what I want to do and where to pull my information from, what variables I should have where etc, I just have some issues with getting down and dirty with the implementation details.

Comment: First, rest assured that jq is a great tool for the kind of task you describe. Second, you indicate you have some flexibility about formattng the CSV file, which makes it hard to pin down the problem you are having.  I'd suggest that you describe one particular format that you have in mind, so that we have something to start with.  Third, you might want to consult the jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ and https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook for CSV-to-JSON examples.

Comment: Here's an example of one csv format:


title,channel,description,filename,filedescription
New Story,65tyc2TLUZsO,Story Description Here,419155345a7b449df3baca76694b64efbec9bcf3983b51e02f92e7ef29fc26ee.pptx,File Description ABC

New Story,65tyc2TLUZsO,Story Description Here,5cdd90989c03d3fb619df6f9294b1fcb537b4f3b55737465930b220507f30e75.pdf,File Description XYZ

Here I've got 1 line per file. But, how do I differentiate that those files go in an array, I've only got 1 "title" value, channel is an array but only gets 1 key:value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.  Start by writing a function to go from your output's nested representation to a flat one:

```
def flatten:
    {
      title: .title,
      id:    .channels[].id,
      story: .description,
    } + .new_files[]
;
```

This will convert your sample json to a stream of objects:

```
{
  "title": "New Story",
  "id": "65tyc2TLUZsO",
  "story": "Story Description Here",
  "filename": "419155345a7b449df3baca76694b64efbec9bcf3983b51e02f92e7ef29fc26ee.pptx",
  "description": "File Description ABC"
}
{
  "title": "New Story",
  "id": "65tyc2TLUZsO",
  "story": "Story Description Here",
  "filename": "5cdd90989c03d3fb619df6f9294b1fcb537b4f3b55737465930b220507f30e75.pdf",
  "description": "File Description XYZ"
}
```

Which can be easily converted to csv like

```
"New Story","65tyc2TLUZsO","Story Description Here","419155345a7b449df3baca76694b64efbec9bcf3983b51e02f92e7ef29fc26ee.pptx","File Description ABC"
"New Story","65tyc2TLUZsO","Story Description Here","5cdd90989c03d3fb619df6f9294b1fcb537b4f3b55737465930b220507f30e75.pdf","File Description XYZ"
```

with a filter like:

```
  flatten
| [.title, .id, .story, .filename, .description ]
| @csv
```

To go from this csv representation to a stream of objects you can use the jq `-s` and `-R` option with a function like

```
def readcsv:
      split("\n")
    | .[]
    | select(length > 0)  
    | split(",")
    | map(fromjson)
    | {
          title:       .[0]
        , id:          .[1]
        , story:       .[2]
        , filename:    .[3]
        , description: .[4]
      }
;
```

and to reassemble that object stream into your original json you can use a function like

```
def unflatten:
      group_by(.title)
    | .[]
    | {
          title:       .[0].title
        , description: .[0].story
      }
      + { channels:    map(.id) | unique | map({id:.}) }
      + { new_files:   map({filename, description}) | unique }
;
```

by combining the filters

```
  [ readcsv ]
| unflatten
```

These functions made some assumptions about the relationships between the fields in your data that will likely need review.  In particular, you probably don't want to completely denormalize the id and filename/description columns as I did.  But once you have tools like these to convert back and forth from nested json to flat csv you can experiment with each representation until you're satisified.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which, for clarity, involves two invocations of jq:

```
 jq -R 'split(",")' input.csv | jq -f program.jq
```

(These two calls could easily be rendered into one as explained below.)

The first invocation emits a stream of arrays.  The first array corresponds to the headers, which again for clarity, will simply be discarded.  The discarding is done here by using `inputs` *without* the -n command-line option.

Here then is program.jq:

```
# Input: an array of "filename, description" pairs
# Output: an array of {filename: _, description: _} objects
def new_files:
  if length == 0 then []
  else [{filename: .[0], description: .[1]}] + (.[2:] | new_files)
  end;
   
inputs
| {title: .[0], channels: [{id: .[1]}], description: .[2] } 
+ {new_files: (.[3:] | new_files) }
```

If your jq does not have `inputs`, then you'd use the `-s` command-line option and replace `inputs` above by `.[1:][]`.

#### Output

With your input, the output in either case (using `inputs` or `.[1:][]`) would be:

```
 {
  "title": "New Story",
  "channels": [
    {
      "id": "65tyc2TLUZsO"
    }
  ],
  "description": "Story Description Here",
  "new_files": [
    {
      "filename": "419155345a7b449df3baca76694b64efbec9bcf3983b51e02f92e7e‌​f29fc26ee.pptx",
      "description": "File Description ABC New Story"
    },
    {
      "filename": "65tyc2TLUZsO",
      "description": "Story Description Here"
    },
    {
      "filename": "5cdd90989c03d3fb619df6f9294b1fcb537b4f3b55737465930b220‌​507f30e75.pdf",
      "description": "File Description XYZ "
    }
  ]
}
```

### Single invocation

One way to avoid invoking jq twice would be to invoke jq with the -R and -s options, using the above definition of `new_files` and the following program:

```
split("\n")
| map(split(","))
| .[1:][]
| {title: .[0], channels: [{id: .[1]}], description: .[2] } 
+ {new_files: (.[3:] | new_files) }
```